Spring redirects to login after successful authentication
Strange behavior with a spring application that uses oauth2 via keycloak. It redirects to the login page after it found a authenticated token. The log says:

Securing POST /create
Authenticated Token
Set SecurityContextHolder to BearerTokenAuthentication ....
Secured POST /create
Redirecting to ...

Spring boot version is 3.2.4
Has anybody a idea about that?
The behavior i expecting is that after the app receives the (correct) token it does not redirect because the call is already authenticated.
